# Which service on Windows 10 hosts is responsible for DNS resolution?

Tags: networking, google-chrome, firefox, dns, resolution

I would have thought that the answer to this question is the DNS Client, but it specifically says in the documentation: "The DNS Client service (dnscache) caches Domain Name System (DNS) names and registers the full computer name for this computer. If the service is stopped, DNS names will continue to be resolved."

So to me, this suggests that some other process is doing the resolution and the DNS Client name is a bit of a misnomer. Does anyone know the answer to this?

And one more thing I was wondering about, I assume that the Windows DNS client which does the resolution is used for command line processes like ping and whatnot. Do browsers like Firefox, Chrome, and Edge use this DNS client? Or do they implement their own DNS client to use?

Comment: Erm "The DNS Client service optimizes the performance of DNS name resolution by storing previously resolved names in memory. **If the DNS Client service is turned off, the computer can still resolve DNS names by using the network's DNS servers.**" Source: [Disable DNS client-side caching on DNS clients | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/dns/troubleshoot/disable-dns-client-side-caching)

Comment: Hmm interesting... so what does it mean to "use the network's DNS Servers"? Like If I am using Windows 10, what service is going to be sending the DNS request if I run a command like, "ping google.com" ?

Comment: [PING vs NSLookup - CB5 Solutions LLC](https://www.cbfive.com/ping-vs-nslookup/)

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft's article
[DNS Client service health](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring/infrastructure-health/vmhealth-windows/winserver-svc-dnscli):

> **Summary**
>
> The DNS Client service **resolves and caches** Domain Name System
> (DNS) names. If this service is stopped, a virtual machine will not be
> able to resolve DNS names and locate Active Directory domain
> controllers.

Conclusion: The DNS Client service does it all, resolving and caching.